# Game Maker Studio

Tags: networking, server, game-maker

Does Game Maker have the capability to do multiplayer in the form of many different rooms. I'm trying to create an online Arena style gladiator type game, and I can't have an obscene amount of characters in one arena, so I need many different rooms, created upon need. Can I have different rooms functioning at the same time in game maker, or so I need to cycle thru them to accomplish everything? The game will be turn based, and will be one where you'd log on to take your action, similar to how Frozen Synapse can be run over an extended length of time. Does anyone have any ideas of how to accomplish this or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

*Yes* you can have multiple rooms funtioning at the same time. I haven't worked much with GameMaker multiplayer, but it is possible since you can do all basic networking stuff. 
How hard it is depends on how you want the game to work: **Peer to peer** or with a **host-server**. 
You an take a look at this tutorial about servers and clients if you haven't already: https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/216754698-Networking-Overview

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a gamemaker server, short answer is **no**.

However, if you'd like to use a dedicated server, you can make it possible, because then the server hosts and stores all game information, and the client (players) only render the information that is important to them.

**Gamemaker Studio** **can not** by its own run two rooms at the same time naturally, so if you'd like to create something more complex, it's the safest to create a dedicated server elsewhere.
Dedicated servers only transact information, but the game renders from the client.